# Inconsistent results using Marketo API - can't find campaign ID

Tags: python, api, marketo

I am using the python library **marketo-rest-api** to pull data from Marketo.  I am just pulling one day to attempt to connect the dots from activities to campaigns.  I am making the following calls:

```
print('Getting Campaigns') 
with open(marketoCampaignsFile,'w') as fcamp:
  campaigns = mc.execute(method='get_multiple_campaigns', id=None, name=None, programName=None, workspaceName=None, batchSize=None)
    for campaign in campaigns:
      jsonString = json.dumps(campaign)
      fcamp.write(jsonString)
fcamp.close()

print('Getting Activities...')
activitiesFile = 'c:\\users\\mark\\marketocsv\\emailActivities.2016-07-26.json'  
with open(activitiesFile,'w',newline='') as fopen:
  for activities in mc.execute(method='get_lead_activities_yield', activityTypeIds=['6','7','8','9','10'], nextPageToken=None, sinceDatetime='2016-07-26', untilDatetime='2016-07-27', batchSize=None, listId=None, leadIds=None):
    for item in activities:
      jsonString = json.dumps(item)
      fopen.write(jsonString+'\n')
fopen.close()
```

What I have found is that the campaign IDs in the activities file do not match any of the campaign IDs in the campaign file.  Does anyone know why this might be?  I need campaign attributes in order to filter the specific activities that I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The activity types that you are downloading don't include the Campaign ID, they provide the Email ID instead.

Comment: Thanks, Jep.  What I am seeing don't appear to be email IDs, but to test it I'll do a "get_email" using one of the IDs and see what I get back.  The reason the campaign ID was important is that it would tell me what workspace it is in and I can "single out" the specific activities that I want to use/access.

Answer (score 1):

So Jep was right.  I did finally find the EmailID.  It's called the `primaryAttributeValueId`. You can link this back to the EmailID provided by Marketo.  I never did find the `campaignID` but I can get to the campaign through the email.  Here's the full JSON from one of the requests:

```
{
    "primaryAttributeValue": "2016-07-Email-To-Customers",
    "activityDate": "2016-07-26T19:05:41Z",
    "attributes": [{
            "value": "0",
            "name": "Choice Number"
        },
        {
            "value": "43182",
            "name": "Step ID"
        }
    ],
    "primaryAttributeValueId": 17030,
    "leadId": 115345,
    "id": 393962103,
    "activityTypeId": 7,
    "campaignId": 15937
}
```